# My locations on my google timeline are showing places i never been,and now my bf thinks im cheating

Tags: location-services

My bf went on my locations timeline and its showing I been to places when I never left the house and it says i drove this long and how long it took and shows a map of the streets I took but I never left the house and they are all in different cities. How is this possible also my ex and I had our emails hooked up so I thought that could be a reason but then seeing it was my house as the start location or the end kocationt I was so confused because once again I never left the house to go anywhere. Someone please help Im sick and tired of telling him I went nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe cause because your Gmail account is signed into the multiple devices may person from those who have logged in with your account cause for this misunderstanding that he went  somewhere and his device is tracked with it or it might be some misunderstanding that he had seen someone likes you and followed her as he was thinking that she was you in relationship their are lot of factors like this and it might not technical questions.

Comment: Is there a way u can see what device was going to these locations?

Comment: Login with your gmail account on gmail.com and see which devices are logged in with your account.